# How to persistently export an environment variable before starting compiz

Tags: nvidia, compiz, window-manager, environment-variables

A few months ago compiz suddenly stopped working. That is, it got to a refreshrate where the redrawing is more than noticeable. It took 5 seconds to redraw a chat window. Ever since I've been using metacity instead, but I've found myself missing some plugins badly.

I found the [following solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3130463&postcount=5):

```
 export __GL_YIELD="NOTHING"; compiz --replace
```

This works fine, everything is fast again with compiz. But how to make sure this variable is always set whenever I run compiz?

I'm using standard nVidia drivers, failed to get the open source ones working.

Comment: Just create a launcher and put it into startup applications..

Comment: That will slowdown booting, as it will **reload** the window manager on boot. First time compiz will boot very, very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the script and edit /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager to point to that script, then gnome-session will still only start compiz once but will use your script to do so.

Or, if it still works, you can put 'export __GL_YIELD="NOTHING"' in your ~/.gnomerc file.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple script to launch Compiz with:

```
# /bin/sh
export __GL_YIELD="NOTHING"
compiz --replace &
```

Name it something like `launch-compiz`, make it exacutable (`chmod +x launch-compiz`), and place it somewhere in your PATH like `/usr/local/bin` Then simply typing `launch-compiz` in the `Alt-F2` run dialog or a terminal will work.

Alternatively, if `export __GL_YIELD="NOTHING"` doesn't have any ill effects under Metacity, you can add it to your `~/.bashrc` file. That will ensure that that environmental variable is always set. Then you can just luanch Compiz as you normally would.

Comment: Making such a script is pretty easy, only that doesn't of course work with how Gnome launches compiz the default way. Besides, what is the & for at the end of the script?